# Using Recursive References in Go

Tags: recursion, reference, go

I want to contain all my commands in a map and map from the command to a function doing the job (just a standard dispatch table). I started with the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func hello() {
    fmt.Print("Hello World!")
}

func list() {
    for key, _ := range whatever {
        fmt.Print(key)
    }
}

var whatever = map[string](func()) {
    "hello": hello,
    "list": list,
}
```

However, it fails to compile because there is a recursive reference between the function and the structure. Trying to forward-declare the function fails with an error about re-definition when it is defined, and the map is at top-level. How do you define structures like this and initialize them on top level *without* having to use an `init()` function.

I see no good explanation in the language definition.

- The forward-reference that exists is for "external" functions and it does not compile when I try to forward-declare the function.
- I find no way to forward-declare the variable either.

**Update:** I'm looking for a solution that do not require you to populate the variable explicitly when you start the program nor in an `init()` function. Not sure if that is possible at all, but it works in all comparable languages I know of.

**Update 2:** [FigmentEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128809/figmentengine) suggested an approach that I gave as answer below. It can handle recursive types and also allow static initialization of the map of all commands.

Comment: I understand your intent, and why you want golang to make it possible. however IMHO this seems like bad practice, as list () is in a container and it knows which container it is in, infact it would only work for this specific container - I think you need some inversion of dependency. all functions when they become non-trivial will require some parameters to operate on. So kill two birds with one stone and have all functions require a context parameter, this can always include a reference to the container, and allows you to support reuse and multiple dispatchers.

Comment: Eh, it would mean that you need to define a recursive type; is that at all possible? This is not really µ-calculus, you know.

Comment: It was not a problem, so there is an example below that is implemented the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by [FigmentEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128809/figmentengine) above, it is actually possible to create a statically initialized array of commands. You have, however, to pre-declare a type that you pass to the functions. I give the re-written example below, since it is likely to be useful to others.

Let's call the new type `Context`. It can contain a circular reference as below.

```
type Context struct {
    commands map[string]func(Context)
}
```

Once that is done, it is possible to declare the array on top level like this:

```
var context = Context {
    commands: map[string]func(Context) {
        "hello": hello,
        "list": list,
    },
}
```

Note that it is perfectly OK to refer to functions defined later in the file, so we can now introduce the functions:

```
func hello(ctx Context) {
    fmt.Print("Hello World!")
}

func list(ctx Context) {
    for key, _ := range ctx.commands {
        fmt.Print(key)
    }
}
```

With that done, we can create a main function that will call each of the functions in the declared context:

```
func main() {
    for key, fn := range context.commands {
        fmt.Printf("Calling %q\n", key)
        fn(context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you might already have found, the [Go specifications](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) states (my emphasis):

> if the initializer of A depends on B, A will be set after B. Dependency analysis does not depend on the actual values of the items being initialized, only on their appearance in the source. A depends on B if the value of A contains a mention of B, contains a value whose initializer mentions B, or *mentions a function that mentions B*, recursively. *It is an error if such dependencies form a cycle.*

So, no, it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. [Issue 1817](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1817) mentions this problem, and Russ Cox does say that the approach in Go might occasionally be over-restrictive. But it is clear and well defined, and workarounds are available.

So, the way to go around it is still by using `init()`. Sorry.

Comment: It confirmed my suspicion. To bad, it is something that make similar problems complicated to solve. I hope they resolve it in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Just populate the map inside a function before using `list()`. Like [that](http://play.golang.org/p/f7MquP3Or2).

Sry I did not see that you wrote "without `init()`": that is not possible.

Comment: That's just an alternative way of of populating it explicitly instead of putting it in the `init()` function.